# Ordering categories by slug vs. name

Tags: categories, slug

I am simply trying to reorder my dropdown options in my header menu.
It pulls from categories and is currently listed them, with the exception of the first, in alphabetical order. I want to list in order of slug. I have tried to change the 'orderby' but seemingly unsuccessfully.

Attached are screen shots of 
a) the dropdown as it currently displays and 
[image]

b) the code for this section of the header.
[image]

All feedback is welcome as I make an update to that code.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In $args you are using

```
'child_of'=>5,
```

why are you using this and if you are using this parameter you should set

```
hide_empty => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `'orderby' => 'name'` to `'orderby' => 'slug'`.
It will work. Check [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

Comment: Thanks! I swear I tried that, but of course I tried it again and it is working just fine. Appreciate the answer.